# Building Android project in Maven: Package * does not exist

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml

I'm building my app using this Maven script. But then I get a whole bunch of errors (see at the end of the posting). It's as if *android.jar* is not found. I checked the path to *android.jar* and it's fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject1.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>MyProject</name>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>4</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>16</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Errors:

```
C:\projectX>mvn install -e
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject
[INFO]    task-segment: [install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [android:generate-sources {execution: default-generate-sources}]
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Copying local resource files to combined resource directory.
[INFO] C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4/tools/aapt [package, -m, -J, \
       C:\projectX\target\generated-sources\r, -M, C:\projectX\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, \
       C:\projectX\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res,-A, C:\projectX\assets, -I, \
       C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\android.jar]

[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Compilation failure

C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[13,22] package org.apache.http does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[23,29] package org.apache.http.entity does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[28,29] package org.apache.http.params does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[30,22] package android.content does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[31,19] package android.util does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[50,9] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DefaultHttpClient
location: class com.projectx.MyClass

C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[10,24] package android.telephony does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[13,18] package android.app does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[19,22] package android.content does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[23,40] package android.content.SharedPreferences does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[25,18] package android.net does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[28,17] package android.os does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[29,25] package android.preference does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[30,19] package android.util does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[31,19] package android.view does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[34,21] package android.widget does not exist
C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[54,36] cannot find symbol
symbol: class Service
public class MyService extends Service {

C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[103,34] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class com.projectx.MyClass

C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[209,46] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class com.projectx.MyClass

C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyClass.java:[229,37] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Context
location: class com.projectx.MyClass

C:\projectX\src\com\projectx\MyService.java:[75,16] cannot find symbol
symbol  : class PendingIntent
location: class com.projectx.MyService

...truncated...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure
```

Comment: NOTE: I used the <verbose> in the maven-compiler-plugin and it doesn't have android.jar in its classpath! How can that possibly work? Nowhere in the documentation does it say I have to add anything to the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was simply that the `<dependencyManagement>` tag is not supposed to be there.

Comment: God bless you sir, i wasted hours on this

Answer (score 0):

this line: C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4/tools/aapt

are you sure the /'s are right and needed there? thatmight be why the android.jar was not picked up..

Comment: First this is output from the maven android plugin (not in the POM.xml file) and I can't modify this. Second, if you look at the end of this same line, it says C:\dev\android-sdk-windows\platforms\android-4\android.jar which is correct (I cut and pasted this in Start>Run and it worked).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your error. But it seems odd to me that you use the android.jar for 2.1.2 (platform 7) and specify platform 4 (Android 1.6). If you want your app to run on 1.6 you should use the android.jar from 1.6. as this is whats available at runtime.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>1.6_r2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

If you want to use features of the AndroidManifest.xml that came with platform 8 (Froyo) like installLocation you should not use platform 4 but 8 instead.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <sdk>
                    <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                    <platform>8</platform>
                </sdk>
                <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
```

If you use Maven > Version 2.0.9 (IIRC) you don't have to specify the version of the plugins anymore. The newest Version is used then automatically.

Comment: I tried both ways and got the same errors. I'm using Maven 2.2.1 and java 1.6.0. You say I can just remove <version>xxx</version> ? From the <dependency> or the <plugin> ??

Comment: Ok I removed the <version> inside the <plugin> and it didn't complain about that. But still I get the same error.